# linkhandler data attribute TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I would like to add a data attribute to the link handler on my website.

I have the following in my setup.ts:

```
config.recordLinks.test {

  forceLink = 0

  typolink {
    parameter = #test
    ATagParams = data-toggle="hover"
  }

}
```

However, the data attribute does not arrive in the source code.

I have no more ideas why this could be. Everything else that is interpreted from https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Linkhandler/Index.html

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: IIRC, not verified: not possible in 8, added via a feature in 9 or 10

Comment: You mean, I should copy the linkhandler from TYPO3 v9 into the extension folder?